# Why are cookies not being destroyed in Java MVC website

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets, cookies

I am attempting to prevent users viewing a webpage if they are not logged in.

Currently the user is able to "login" which sets a cookie for 24 hours. I achieve this using AJAX which forwards to the admin page after creating the "loggedIn" cookie.

When a user navigates to `MainController?page=logout` it should delete the cookie and forward the user to the login page, which it appears to do.

But when navigating to `MainController?page=admin` the user should be forwarded to the login page if no cookies exist, but instead the admin page loads. I'm assuming that I'm not deleting the cookies properly?

Here is the AJAX call to check user credentials when logging in:

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    var postData    = $("#loginForm").serializeArray();
    var username    = $("#username").val();
    var password    = $("#password").val();
    var botCatcher  = $(".botCatcher").val();

    if(username.length > 3 && password.length > 3 && botCatcher.length == 0){
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url : "MainController",
                data : postData,
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    if(data == "success"){
                        window.location.href = "MainController?page=admin";
                    }else if(data == "nope"){
                        $(".test").html("<p>Login details incorrect. Please try again.</p>");
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    $(".test").html("<p>ss"+errorThrown+textStatus+jqXHR+"</p>");
                    }
                });

        }else{
            $(".test").html("<p>Unable to login: ensure details are correct.</p>");
        }
});
```

This is how I'm setting the cookie in the `doPost` method of the MainController servlet and outputing "success" to allow JQuery to forward to the admin webpage.

```
Cookie loggedIn = new Cookie("loggedIn", "true");
loggedIn.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24);
response.addCookie(loggedIn);
out.print("success");
```

This is how I control the navigation, as you can see the logout case should delete the cookie which means that the admin case should forward the user to the login page because the cookie object is null? Instead it loads the admin page. - This is actuated using a link on the admin page pointing to `MainController?page=logout` which is supposed to delete the cookie and forward to the login page, which it appears to do. But I can still navigate back to the admin page without needing to login.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String page         = getPageName(request.getParameter("page"));
    Cookie cookies[]    = request.getCookies();

    switch (page) {

    case "admin":
        if (cookies == null) {
            page = "login";
            return;
        }
        break;
    case "logout":

        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            cookie.setMaxAge(0);
            cookie.setPath("/");
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }

        page = "login";
        break;

    }
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(views + getPageFilename(page));
        rd.forward(request, response);

}
```

Why is it loading the admin page instead of forwarding to the login page ( and thus preventing users not logged in to view this page ). Am I not deleting the cookies correctly?

Comment: In the `case "admin":` branch, the code exits the procedure with `return`, the assigned value to `page` ("login") is never used and the request is not forwarded. (Maybe this is not related to the problem.)

Comment: Is that right? I assumed it sets the page to "login" and then exits out of the switch/case statement only.

Comment: A `return` will leave the method, a `break` will leave the `switch`.